# how to implement real time chat app using firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to implement simple chat app provided: [github.com/firebase/friendlychat][1]

however, it works in a test device but not in real one. it stays in the login page and doesn't proceed to next while trying to login with google id. i have already enabled the required auth in firebase as well.

where did i miss as i have enabled all the procedures as instructed in the tutorial.

**SignInActivity:**

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private SignInButton mSignInButton;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    // Assign fields
    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    // Set click listeners
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Initialize FirebaseAuth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult authResult) {
    if (authResult != null) {
        // Welcome the user
        FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Go back to the main activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Google Sign In failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ChatActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: When you say it 'it works in a test device but not in real one' what do you mean specifically?

Comment: i tried that app and run successfully in my emulator and tested with other mobile device. however after i uploaded to playstore (beta testing) it stays in the log in page and nothing happens then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the fingerPrint from your app and add it to firebase, then authentication through google will work.